# Magento 2.3 - How to display a message when unset a shipping method using aroundEstimateByExtendedAddress plugin?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

Want to display a message after certain conditions, how to achieve that?

```
class ShipmentEstimationPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function aroundEstimateByExtendedAddress(
        ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
    ) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testshipping.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
        $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

        $brands =  array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $loaded_product = $product->load($item->getProductId());
            $product = $product->load($item->getProductId());
            $brand = null;
            $brand=$loaded_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($loaded_product);
            $brand = strval($brand);
            $subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
            // $items = array($brand);
            array_push($brands, $brand);
        }

        $size = sizeof($brands);
        $logger->info($brands);
        $logger->info($size);
        $pelican = in_array("Pelican",$brands);
        $nanuk = in_array("Nanuk", $brands);
        $other = in_array("Other", $brands);

        $logger->info("Pelican");
        $logger->info($pelican);
        $logger->info("Nanuk");
        $logger->info($nanuk);
        $logger->info("Other");
        $logger->info($other);

        $code=$address->getPostcode();
        $region=$address->getRegionId();
        $logger->info($code);
        $logger->info($region);

        $check = stripos($code, '0') === 1;
        $logger->info(stripos($code, '0') === 1);
        $shippingMethods = $proceed($cartId, $address);
        if ($code) {
            if ($check ) {
                foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                    if ($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping") {
                        unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($region) { // Check is regionid exists in request
            $regionid = $region;
            if ($regionid == 69 || $regionid == 72 || $regionid == 73 || $regionid == 75 || $regionid == 78) {
                foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                    if ($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping") {
                        unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (in_array("Pelican",$brands) || in_array("Nanuk",$brands)) {
            if ($subTotal >= 150) {
                if ( in_array("Other", $brands) || in_array("SKB", $brands)) {
                    if ($regionid == 69 || $regionid == 72 || $regionid == 73 || $regionid == 75 || $regionid == 78 || $check) {
                        foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                            if($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping"){
                                unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                            }
                        }
                        $logger->info("Pelican & Non Pelican found");
                        $logger->info("You are not eligible for free shipping");
                    } else {
                        foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                            if ($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping") {
                                unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                            }
                        }
                        $logger->info("Pelican & Non Pelican found");
                        $logger->info("You may be eligible for free shipping");
                        //not Working
                        $question = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface');
                        $question->addWarning(__("Warning"));
                        //not working
                        //Want to display message here
                        // echo "You may be eligible for free shipping. Contact at websales@productioncase.com for you free quote";
                    }
                } else {
                    $logger->info("Only Pelican/Nanuk found");
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                    if($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping"){
                        unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                if ($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping") {
                    unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $shippingMethods;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//you can use magento exception class to throw message after namespace

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class ShipmentEstimationPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

```
public function aroundEstimateByExtendedAddress(
    ShipmentEstimationInterface $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
) {
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testshipping.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
    $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

    $brands =  array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $loaded_product = $product->load($item->getProductId());
        $product = $product->load($item->getProductId());
        $brand = null;
        $brand=$loaded_product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($loaded_product);
        $brand = strval($brand);
        $subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
        // $items = array($brand);
        array_push($brands, $brand);
    }

    $size = sizeof($brands);
    $logger->info($brands);
    $logger->info($size);
    $pelican = in_array("Pelican",$brands);
    $nanuk = in_array("Nanuk", $brands);
    $other = in_array("Other", $brands);

    $logger->info("Pelican");
    $logger->info($pelican);
    $logger->info("Nanuk");
    $logger->info($nanuk);
    $logger->info("Other");
    $logger->info($other);

    $code=$address->getPostcode();
    $region=$address->getRegionId();
    $logger->info($code);
    $logger->info($region);

    $check = stripos($code, '0') === 1;
    $logger->info(stripos($code, '0') === 1);
    $shippingMethods = $proceed($cartId, $address);
    if ($code) {
        if ($check ) {
            foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                if ($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping") {
                    unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                  //through exception using magento exeption class where ever you want
                    throw new LocalizedException(__('Your message'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($region) { // Check is regionid exists in request
        $regionid = $region;
        if ($regionid == 69 || $regionid == 72 || $regionid == 73 || $regionid == 75 || $regionid == 78) {
            foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                if ($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping") {
                    unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                    throw new LocalizedException(__('Your message'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (in_array("Pelican",$brands) || in_array("Nanuk",$brands)) {
        if ($subTotal >= 150) {
            if ( in_array("Other", $brands) || in_array("SKB", $brands)) {
                if ($regionid == 69 || $regionid == 72 || $regionid == 73 || $regionid == 75 || $regionid == 78 || $check) {
                    foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                        if($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping"){
                            unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                            throw new LocalizedException(__('Your message'));
                        }
                    }
                    $logger->info("Pelican & Non Pelican found");
                    $logger->info("You are not eligible for free shipping");
                } else {
                    foreach ($shippingMethods as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                        if ($shippingMethod->getMethodCode() == "freeshipping") {
                            unset($shippingMethods[$key]);
                        }
                    }
                    $logger->info("Pelican & Non Pelican found");
                    $logger->info("You may be eligible for free shipping");
                    //not Working
```